# How external kernel module look for exported symbol during modpost

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have 3 external kernel modules that have dependency from each other. More specifically, C contains symbol from B, which contains symbol from A.

I try to build module in the following orders.

```sh
make -C <Kernel dir> 
make -C <kernel dir> KERNELRELEASE=$(KERNEL_VER) modules
make -C <kernel dir> KERNELRELEASE=$(KERNEL_VER) INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$(INSTALL_PATH) modules_install

make -C <kernel_dir> M=<module_A_dir> modules;
make -C <kernel_dir> M=<module_A_dir> INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$(INSTALL_PATH) modules_install;

make -C <kernel_dir> M=<module_B_dir> modules;
make -C <kernel_dir> M=<module_B_dir> INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$(INSTALL_PATH) modules_install;

make -C <kernel_dir> M=<module_C_dir> modules;
make -C <kernel_dir> M=<module_C_dir> INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$(INSTALL_PATH) modules_install;
```

When compile module B, during modpost, it cannot recognize the exported symbols from module A, claiming they were undefined.

The message is the following:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/workingdir/kernel/linux-5.4.x'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
ERROR: "backport_dependency_symbol" [/home/user/workingdir/extModB/moduleB.ko] undefined!
ERROR: "cfg80211_moduleA_cmd" [/home/user/workingdir/extModB/moduleB.ko] undefined!
```

I understand that I can simply include Module.symvers from A into B, but there is one problem. The license for module A is (GPL), while B's module license is (BSD/GPL), but license C is (Proprietary). If simply configure `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS` to include Module.symvers from other module directory, I will run into license issue when compiling.

So my question is, is there anyway to install external module A, so when compiling kernel module B, during modpost stage, it will automatically identify the module A within the `INSTALL_MOD_PATH`?

Comment: You should run `depmod` after each update of the modules in the target directory.

Comment: Sorry,, I am trying to cross compile a Kernel for a embedded system.  Isn't running depmod upddate thes the module dependency on the host system itself?  Of course, I might be mistaken.  If so, how would I run my depmod command?

Comment: You even haven't shown this _small_ detail about cross-compiling! But in any case, you need to run cross-compiled `depmod` inside your instalation folder.

Comment: Well, I tried running depmod -b $(Staging) -a -v 5.4.260 after installation of module A, but still the same error happens during modpost when building module B.

Comment: Have you exported your symbols with `EXPORT_SYMBOL()`?

Comment: Yes, I verified it and its exported correctly.  The target directory where I install modules staging/lib/mdoules/5.4.260/ contains 
modules.symbols:361:alias symbol:backport_dependency_symbol compat

I am looking at kbuild and see if I can find anything relates to it.

Comment: (Note, if you want to notify users about your new comments, add @USER to them. It is by luck I have checked this question again.)

Answer (score 0):

After checking with openwrt, it did something different, which is removing include/mac80211-backport/linux/module.h that existed within module A,  when compiing module B, somehow magically modpost won't be complaining for "backport_dependency_symbol" not defined because such function calls no longer existed within the header file, so modpost won't look for actual symbol.

It's a different approach that Openwrt takes since as system engineer, we tend to include all functions definitions rather than removing partially.